# How to compress all world population simple poll

Tags: database, data-structures, compression

Imagine you have to ask every person in the world about their happiness in scale from 1 to 10. Everyone responds. There are up to 8 bn people so you have to use bigint for the key (let's assume we already have identities in another DB and we need only keys), and you actually have almost 8 bn unique records. Then, for each record you have to store a value from 1 to 10 - in most DBs that will map to the byte datatype (this is just an assumption, we could measure happiness in a scale from 0 to 255 as well).

8bn people * (8 bytes key + 1 byte value) = 64 Gb key values + 8 Gb value =  72 Gb total size.

Is it possible to reduce substantially the storage size for the same task in any mainstream database, e.g. SQL Server or MySql?

I am not going to make such a poll and do not have so many users, the big key is a result of a cartesian product of several other int keys, and in the long run I could have billions of records with simple numeric value for each combination of smaller ids.

Comment: If you just want to save the results you could count the number of people by their choice. Then you would have one table with 10 rows.

Comment: @TheHippo I need to save each key. Otherwise that would be trivial

Comment: As far as information theory is concerned, and assuming the keys carries no information that couldn't be derived from the position in the sequence of records (as it is usually the case with integer primary keys), this data contains 8 * 10^9 * log_2 10 bits of information. That's 26575424759.1 according to Google, which is a little less than 3.1 GiB. So your encoding is pretty damn inefficient. I'm also assuming there's nothing about the data which a compression program could exploit to get it any smaller -- no patterns, uniform distribution, etc.

Comment: @delnan what about storing the data for future (reasonably fast) access (not in a glacier for once-in-a-life-time parsing 100 years later)? Keys are important, and they are not sequential, but unique.

Comment: Depends on what operations you need and how much information is actually in the keys. You can get pretty close to the above bound by bit-aligning the records, i.e. storing each 1..10 number in 4 bit. That wastes about 4/16 = 25% space, but you get random read/write access. If you need to add/remove records at random positions, things get more complicated, but I think 72 GiB is still excessive.

Comment: The use case is to know how "happy" are my users when they come back to the site (read heavy, writes are in background and not real-time, but storage size is a concern).

Comment: Sure I do not have so many users, the big key is a result of a cartesian product of several other int ids, and in the long run I could have billions of records with simple numeric value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to **store** the key to be able to use the key. You just need an array with the responses. So 8 bn people gives 8 bn bytes. So that's 8 GB.

If you only want, say 16 possible answers, you can pack two answers in one byte, and you are down to 4 GB.

If you really want this to be small & fast a flat file could be just as good if not better. This depends on the type of usage you have.

But if you really want it in a table, but still keep it small you need to get rid of the key on each record. This you e.g. can do this by sharing a key between records like:

```
Key      n0 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 n8 n9
00000000  7  1  2 13  7  8  9 11  2  9
00000010  3  7  8  9 11  2  6  7  9 12
```

where answers `00000000-00000009` are packed on record `00000000` and answers `00000010-00000019` are packed on record `00000010`

Comment: but how I should store this in a database to be able to access any key in a reasonable time?

Comment: @V.B. If your database doesn't allow this optimization, ditch your data base and store it otherwise (e.g. in a BLOB or in an external file). There's not much you'll need the DB for, you'll be able to optimize a lot, etc.

Comment: So this gives 14 bytes per row and 800 mn rows, or 11 Gb instead of 72. Very good! What if there were 43 bn people in the world?

Comment: You have plenty of options if you want to fine tune. You can add more than 10 records per key. Also - you can pack the answers so you store 2 answers per byte

Answer (score 0):

If keys are sparsely distributed, you're stuck with having to explicitly pair a response with a key.  You could save that by storing this poll in another table that already has a key column thus saving the effort.

If keys are continuous, Ebbe's approach will work best.  If you MUST use table structures, you can split this data into, for example, 1024 shards and have the first 10 bits of the key implied by the identity of the table when doing key lookups.

You can also save some storage from the tail end of the key.  For example, we'd like to not store the last 10 bit of the key.  Then have the key be truncated by 10 bits and store a blob there, which would be a flat array of 1024 responses.

You can save the poll data (1 byte value) by creating 10 tables for each answer and inserting keys into each depending on the poll answer (this won't work in combination with some things above, plus it won't scale if your poll answer range is large).